# ResouceGroup().Location in nested template confusion

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have nested template below. It seems that `resourcegroup().location` for container registry refers to resourcegroup defined in parent template and not the one it's being deployed via `nestedTemplate`. How do I properly refer to location of resource group in nested template instead?

```
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "nestedTemplate",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[variables('SharedResourceGroup')]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "name": "[variables('ACRName')]",
                            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
                            "apiVersion": "2017-10-01",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "comments": "Container registry for storing docker images",
                            "sku": {
                                "name": "Standard",
                                "tier": "Standard"
                            },
                            "properties": {
                                "adminUserEnabled": true
                            }
                        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use linked template, not inline template. the thing with inline template it renders it before deploying it. so it renders it as if it was part of the parent template.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
    "name": "linkedTemplate",
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
            "uri":"https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/AzureTemplates/newStorageAccount.json",
            "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parametersLink": {
            "uri": "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/AzureTemplates/newStorageAccount.parameters.json",
            "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

It will work this way. I'd suggest not using nested inline templates.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates

Comment: Thanks but problem with linked template is that you can not deploy with parent template itself and have to manually host it somewhere and then deal with authentication etc. Inline is perfect from deployment point of view.

Comment: you cannot really use any cool features linked templates offer in inline templates and (as you just witnessed) behaviour is edgy, so linked templates are a lot safer\straight forward.